# scipy.integrate.quad precision on big numbers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, calculus

I try to compute such an integral (actually cdf of exponential distribution with its pdf) via `scipy.integrate.quad()`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(x):
    return .5 * np.exp(-.5 * x)

print quad(g, a=0., b=np.inf)
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**6)
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**5)
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**4)
```

And the result is as follows:

```
(1.0, 3.5807346295637055e-11)
(0.0, 0.0)
(3.881683817604194e-22, 7.717972744764185e-22)
(1.0, 1.6059202674761255e-14)
```

All the attempts to use a big upper integration limit yield an incorrect answer though the usage of `np.inf` solves the problem.

Similiar case is discussed in [scipy issue #5428 at GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5428).

What should I do to avoid such an error in integrating other density functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to `np.exp(-x)` quickly becoming very small as `x` increases, which results in evaluating as zero due to limited numerical precision. For example, even for `x` as small as `x=10**2*`, `np.exp(-x)` evaluates to `3.72007597602e-44`, whereas `x` values of order `10**3` or above result in `0`.

I do not know the implementation specifics of `quad`, but it probably performs some kind of sampling of the function to be integrated over the given integration range. For a large upper integration limit, most of the samples of `np.exp(-x)` evaluate to zero, hence the integral value is underestimated. (Note that in these cases the provided absolute error by `quad` is of the same order as the integral value which is an indicator that the latter is unreliable.)

One approach to avoid this issue is to restrict the integration upper bound to a value above which the numerical function becomes very small (and, hence, contributes marginally to the integral value). From your code snipet, the value of `10**4` appears to be a good choice, however, a value of `10**2` also results in an accurate evaluation of the integral.

Another approach to avoid numerical precision issues is to use a module that performs computation in *arbitrary* precision arithmetic, such as `mpmath`. For example, for `x=10**5`, `mpmath` evaluates `exp(-x)` as follows (using the native `mpmath` exponential function)

```
import mpmath as mp
print(mp.exp(-10**5))
```

> `3.56294956530937e-43430`

Note how small this value is. With the standard hardware numerical precision (used by `numpy`) this value becomes `0`.

`mpmath` offers an integration function (`mp.quad`), which can provide an accurate estimate of the integral for arbitrary values of the upper integral bound.

```
import mpmath as mp

print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, mp.inf]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**13]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**8]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**5]))
```

> ```
> 1.0
> 0.999999650469474
> 0.999999999996516
> 0.999999999999997
> ```

We can also obtain even more accurate estimates by increasing the precision to, say, `50` decimal points (from `15` which is the standard precision)

```
mp.mp.dps = 50; 

print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, mp.inf]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**13]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**8]))
print(mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**5]))
```

> ```
> 1.0
> 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999829880262
> 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997463
> 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998
> ```

In general, the cost for obtaining this accuracy is an increased computation time.

P.S.: It goes without saying that if you are able to evaluate your integral analytically in the first place (e.g., with the help of `Sympy`) you can forget all the above.

Comment: mpmath isn't infallible either: `mp.quad(lambda x : .5 * mp.exp(-.5 * x), [0, 10**20])` -> `2.20502636520112e-56`. The point is that numerical integration of functions is impossible without some "smoothness" conditions --- the function must not have too sharp "spikes" in the integration interval. When the integration interval is very large, the function `exp(-x/2)` is very "spiky", which causes the problems.

Comment: @pv. Indeed, thanks for the comment. However, if you increase the precision enough, there is no such problem. For example, try `mp.mp.dps = 100` before calling the `mp.quad`

Comment: Increasing the accuracy just pushes the upper bound upward, try `10**120`. It also increases the cost of the computation, which in this case is unnecessary. The problem is not that the function values are so small they are below the floating point range, but the fact that the function when scaled to the integration interval, is very spiky, which misleads the error estimation of the integration algorithm.

Comment: @Stelios is `mpmath` compatible with `scipy`, `pandas` and other popular packages?

Comment: Coming from the Mathematica world, I'm used to doing symbolic simplification first, then integrate with machine precision, then cranking up WorkingPrecision. I guess the philosophy is similar here. I like that the same ideology still roughly holds :-) and it solved my problem like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Use the `points` argument to tell the algorithm where the support of your function roughly is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(x):
    return .5 * np.exp(-.5 * x)

print quad(g, a=0., b=10**3, points=[1, 100])
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**6, points=[1, 100])
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**9, points=[1, 100])
print quad(g, a=0., b=10**12, points=[1, 100])
```

Comment: Comparing the output of these case with that of `np.quad(g, a=0., b=100)`, it seems that this approach essentially sets the upper limit to be 100, irrespective of the actual user input. Of course, this may be just fine for the OP purposes.

Comment: It does not. The integrator does sample the function beyond x > 100, but it is of course an elementary fact that that part of the integral gives very small contribution.

Comment: @pv after reading quad docstring I can't understand how your advice helps. Points 1 and 100 aren't points of discontinuity

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov: it forces the integrator to sample the function at those points. Otherwise, for large integration interval it'll sample points `a + eps * (b - a)` where eps is some small number --- but if `b - a` is very big, it will miss the peak close to x=0.